# MEF composition GetExports performance

Tags: mef, composition

Our .NET application is composed using MEF. Ia am tracking down performance issues at start up. I see that my UI thread is waiting a lot on composing parts from catalog. 
Particularly, System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AggregateCatalog.GetExports(ImportDefinition)  method seems quite slow because it internally it uses a List and while AddRange-ing it does a lot of object comparison. Also, it is called in my case about 500 THOUSAND times... So, obviously, this is HOT SPOT. I've attached an image of inverted stack leading to underlying problem. 
Does anyone experience the same with MEF or we may be using it improperly? 
How can we, perhaps, help MEF avoid doing what it does now?
Thank you, 
Alexei
[image]

Comment: Do you call any container methods explicitly in your solution in order to get instances, exports and so on?

Comment: Yes, we do, a lot: _container.GetExportedValue<T>(). Why?

Comment: Me too, tracking down performance issues at start up, any idea?

Comment: Unearthing this as I have similar issues when initializing MEF composition